# JavaFX Alert on Fullscreen mode focus out from the application

Tags: javafx-8

I want a JavaFX Alert appear on the top of my full screen stage. How do I do that?

Currently when the alert appears, it get focus out from the application and make hide the application until I response to the alert. My alert having only these properties.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
alert.setContentText("aaa");
alert.setTitle("bbb");
alert.setHeaderText("ccc");
alert.show();
```